# System hang and increased startup time due to svchost.exe

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, wsus, windows-service

I have a domain network, most of the windows 7 systems are taking too much time to startup and settle up. High disk activity and increased memory usage are noticed. I have a locally hosted WSUS server which i doubt causing the issue. The high memory usage issue is fixed after I installed the Microsoft patches KB3050265 and KB3102810. however the machine's are taking too much time to settle up after booting.
    I tried clearing the SoftwareDistribution folder and by clearing old updates.

Comment: Try too boot them up without network connectivity so you can make out if the problem is related to the machines or your connection to the WSUS server...

Comment: `the machine's are taking too much time to settle up after booting` - What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Why would WSUS cause the computers to boot up slowly? I manage an environment with 26 WSUS servers and well over 3,000 WSUS clients and have never heard of such a thing. From a technical perspective, what about WSUS would cause such an issue?

Comment: The disk activity is high for 10 to 15 minutes and only after that the users will be able to work smoothly. The SoftwareDistribtution directory size getting size about 700 MB to 1.5 GB. That's why I am doubting the WSUS.

Answer (score -7):

You can defrag disc, not using build-in defrag but find an best defragmentator , i recommend mydefrag, and optimize your disc too.

Stop unneeded services, if you do not need New updates, don't use wuaserv. Especially for me, this service never did work. Even if work, its taking too much time to detect available updates and too much resources. 50% cpu Intel dual 2ghz and 90 % ram of 3GB. .. and it use much disc speed too.

Look at startup, again look at services, disable powerfull design and effect. Not by program, but in regedit.

I installed win XP with working Flash Player , eset nod 32 , ccleaner ... on 1x1GHz cpu, 256MB SDRAM and lower than 100 MB vram gpu. .. all was working fine, especially Flash Player , which only version 10.X was correct. You can do much if you do it the right way.